# Как часто числа 0 и 1 встречаются в массиве

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, вывод, for

Создал массив из 10 чисел: `0` и `1`, инициализировал каждый индекс массива как 0 или 1. Написал цикл:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        count0++;
        System.out.println(count0);
```

Получил ответ `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, т. к. `0` встречается в массиве `5` раз. Как мне правильно написать цикл, чтобы получить ответ только 5?

Comment: вынести печать за скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [`IntStream.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--), который возвращает количество элементов в текущем стриме:

```java
int[] arr = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};
long count =
    // открываем stream по массиву
    Arrays.stream(arr)
        // фильтруем стрим - отбираем
        // только элементы, равные '0'
        .filter(e -> e == 0)
        // считаем количество элементов
        .count();
// выводим результат
System.out.println(count); // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас код подразумевает, что в каждом повторном проходе цикла будет выводиться актуальное состояние count0. Вынесите System.out.println из цикла, чтобы он выполнялся один раз в конце.

Answer (score 2):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        System.out.println(foo(arr1));
    }

    static int foo(int[] arr) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == 0) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```